# How to run icacls with runas successfully?

Tags: c#, cmd, runas, icacls

I have a problem with my code which I cannot find (I am unable to debug due to different servers issue). I am trying to run a command that set permissions on a folder but I also want to run it as s different user. So when I start my program and it gets to this point it either goes on (opening a command console) and no permissions have been granted or it freezes my form and no console opens or permissions have been granted.

So in the first case I use this code:

```
string grantAccess = @"runas /savecred /user:domain\user1 ""icacls \\ext.kfg\dfs\GroupFTP\Data_Exchange\" + login + @" /grant: GFK\D-RE-AP-RT-GIM-USER:(OI)(CI)(RC,RD,WD,AD,REA,WEA,X,DC,RA,WA)""";

Process.Start("cmd.exe", grantAccess);
```

and the second case I use:

```
string grantAccess = @"/savecred ""icacls \\ext.gfk\dfs\GroupFTP\Data_Exchange\" + login + @" /grant: GFK\D-RE-AP-RT-GIM-USER:(OI)(CI)(RC,RD,WD,AD,REA,WEA,X,DC,RA,WA)""";

Process processGrant = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfoGrant = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfoGrant.Domain = "domain";
startInfoGrant.UserName = "user1";
startInfoGrant.Password = userPassword; // this is a SecureString 
startInfoGrant.FileName = "cmd.exe";        
startInfoGrant.Verb = "runas";          // I've tried it with or without this line
startInfoGrant.Arguments = grantAccess;
startInfoGrant.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfoGrant.UseShellExecute = false;
processGrant.StartInfo = startInfoGrant;
processGrant.Start();
processGrant.WaitForExit();
```

Can somebody tell me why it is not working?

Comment: I solved it myself after some more brainbusting. This is what workde for me at the end:                                                                                                 string grantAccess = @"\\ext.fgk\dfs\GroupFTP\Data_Exchange\" + login + @" /grant FGK\D-RE-AP-RT-GIM-USER:(OI)(CI)(RC,RD,WD,AD,REA,WEA,X,DC,RA,WA)";                                                    and then the command was just an overload of the Process.Start  Process.Start("icacls.exe", grantAccess, "user", userPassword, "domain");